# Java - how post event to UI thread or call a function of UI thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I have a java code that looks like this:

```
//UI thread
//Some code
Job j = new Job(jobName) {

@Override
public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
try {
                    //Some code
                    SomeFunc();
                    //Some code
                    return Status.OK_STATUS;

    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
    }
}
};
j.schedule();
```

The problem is that the `SomeFunc();` must be called from the UI thread.

I'm new to java, so can you please help me with showing the best methods for posting event to UI thread or calling a function of UI thread?

Comment: you have to be more clear- what UI framework you use?

Comment: I'm developing an eclipse plugin, and using Eclipse SDK.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into SWT then

Comment: See http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_display

Comment: @Andrejs - post it to an answer, so I will be able to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worth having a look at the [Eclipse Jobs and Background Processing](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_display) tutorial by Lars Vogel. There are good [examples](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_jobs) on how to run code on the UI thread from Eclipse Jobs.

Answer (score 4):

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
  @Override
  public void run() {
     // your UI code
  }
});
```

or you can use SwingWorker, its another choice:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate where and how to call this piece of code?

Comment: 'EventQueue.invokeLater(...)' is often written as 'SwingUtilities.invokeLater( ... )'

Note that this applies to Swing and not SWT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857531/swt-swing-threads-n-hell

Comment: @sara: Just replace your call to `SomeFunc` with the code @Wajdy posted and put the call to `SomeFunc` inside the `run` method.

Answer (score 2):

In SWT, use Display.syncExec() as in [this snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet7.java) or Display.asyncExec().