# setBackground method doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jlabel, conways-game-of-life, setbackground

So I'm trying to build conways game of life and everything works except when I update the background color on the label when it needs to be changed to black or white. When I click on the labels they change color and when I first make the labels it changes the color. When I run the game loop and it checks to see how many other cells it's touching and it tries to update the color of the label it doesn't work.

The method that updates the color seems to work because I put print statements in it and they printed it only works when I remove the keylistener stuff then it will update the color. Literaly everythings works except for the `setBackground` method. (I'll add a bunch of comments when the not working `setBackground` method is).

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main
{ 
  public static final int arrY = 28;
  public static final int arrX = 28;
  public static int[][] arr = new int[arrX][arrY];
  public static int[][] endArr = new int[arrX][arrY];
  public static final int CELL = 1;
  public static final int DEADCELL = 0; 
  public static boolean stop = true;
  public static int generations = 0;
  static MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

  public static int isTouching(int X, int Y) {
    
    int integer = 0;
    if (X != 0 && Y != 0) {
      if (arr[X-1][Y-1] == CELL) {
        integer++;
      }
    }
     if (X != 0) {
      if (arr[X-1][Y] == CELL) {
        integer++;
      }
     }
     if (X != 0) {
      if (arr[X-1][Y+1] == CELL) {
        integer++;
      }
     }
    if (Y != 0) {
      if (arr[X][Y-1] == CELL) {
        integer++;
      }
    }
    if (arr[X][Y+1] == CELL) {
      integer++;
    }
    if (Y != 0) {
      if (arr[X+1][Y-1] == CELL) {
        integer++;
      }
    }
    if (arr[X+1][Y] == CELL) {
      integer++;
    }
    if (arr[X+1][Y+1] == CELL) {
      integer++;
    } 
    return integer;
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    

  for (int i = 1; i < arrX; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < arrY; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = 0;
      endArr[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }  
    
  frame.makeBoard(arr); 
  }
  public static void loop() {
    while (!stop) {
     if (stop) {
       break;
     }
      generations++;
      for (int i = 0; i <= arrX - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= arrY - 2; j++) {
          int touch = isTouching(i, j);
          if (arr[i][j] == CELL && touch < 2) {
            frame.labelWhite(i, j);
            endArr[i][j] = DEADCELL;
          }
          if (arr[i][j] == CELL && touch == 3) {
            
            frame.labelBlack(i,j);
            endArr[i][j] = CELL;
          }
          if (arr[i][j] == CELL && touch > 3) {
           
            frame.labelWhite(i,j);
            endArr[i][j] = DEADCELL;
          }
          if (arr[i][j] == DEADCELL && touch == 3) {
           
            frame.labelBlack(i,j);
            endArr[i][j] = CELL;
          }
          if (arr[i][j] == CELL && touch == 2) {
            
            frame.labelBlack(i,j);
            endArr[i][j] = CELL;
          }
        }
      }  
   
      for (int i = 0; i < arrX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrY; j++) {
          arr[i][j] = endArr[i][j];
          endArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public static void stop() {
    if (stop == false) {
        stop = true;
      } else if (stop == true) {
        stop = false;
        loop();
    }
  } 
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
  public static JLabel[][] labelArr = new JLabel[28][28];

  MyFrame(){
    this.setTitle("Oliver's Game of Life");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1000,1000);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void makeBoard(int[][] arr) {
    int addX = 0;
    int addY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Main.arrX; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < Main.arrY; j++) {
       labelArr[i][j] = new JLabel();
      // first two move second two make size
      labelArr[i][j].setBounds(addY, addX, 25, 25);
      labelArr[i][j].setOpaque(true);
      this.add(labelArr[i][j]);
      labelArr[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
      labelArr[i][j].setVisible(true);
      int ii = i;
      int jj = j;
        
      labelArr[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    
                    labelArr[ii][jj].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    Main.arr[ii][jj] = Main.CELL;
                    Main.endArr[ii][jj] = Main.CELL;
                }
            });
      
        addX += 25;
      }
      addX = 0;
      addY += 25;
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyChar()) {
      case 'a': Main.stop();
        break;
    }
  }
  @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 }

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
 }
  public void labelWhite(int i, int j) {
    //this doesn't work
    labelArr[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
    //this doesn't work
  }
  public void labelBlack(int i, int j) {
   //this doesn't work
    labelArr[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
   //this doesn't work
  } 
}
```

Comment: *"it only works when i remove the keylistner stuff then it will update the color."*  what do you mean by that? So the code as you posted it now does work or not?

Comment: it doesnt work im saying it only works without the keyListener

Comment: And you have some print statements in `labelWhite` and `labelBlack` and they get printed but only the color doesn't change? And when you click a cell it does work? That doesn't seem to make any sense to me ...

Comment: in order to test to actually see if the method is working I put print system.out.println("); and they printed so the method label black and label white are working its just set background is not

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind (I never really was a frontend-dev so I might be wrong) is a theading problem, ie you cannot update UI components from a thread other then the main thread. Might it be your loop is running on a different thead?

Comment: maybe but how would i fix that

Comment: See for instance here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976575/java-how-post-event-to-ui-thread-or-call-a-function-of-ui-thread

Comment: wait no that wont fix it because when I took out the keylistener it would change the UI

Comment: As said I've never been to deep into UI development, but you are starting your loop in the handler of a key pressed event and it might be, that this  is running on a different thread. When you did without keylistener you probably just started your loop from the `main` method, ie the main thread